# SQL query join table clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join a columns from 2 different tables.

- 1st table is `TBWORKFLOWPROCESS`, column name is `processname`
- 2nd table is `TBLSTAPP`, column names are `isforreconsideration`, `isforamendment`

My query is:

```
select 
    pro.processname, app.isforreconsideration, app.isforamendment 
from 
    TBWORKFLOWPROCESS pro 
left join 
    TBLSTAPP app on app.applicationtype = pro.workflowid 
where  
    sequenceno >= 10 and pro.workflowid = 1 
group by 
    pro.processname, app.isforreconsideration, app.isforamendment
```

Output:

```
processname                 isforreconsideration          isforamendment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
booked
booked,doc pending
cancelled
rejected
```

The output is correct but what I want is this.

```
processname               
---------------
booked
booked,doc pending
cancelled
rejected
isforreconsideration
isforamendment
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks guys.

Comment: Give us a good example data. We cant help you without it. Try changing left join with inner join and right join... But this is only a hunch...

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question you asked leaves a lot to be explained, and based on what I could understand and a lot assumptions, I think you want to incorporate the values of the two attributes (isforreconsideration and isforamendment) for the same condition and show them under the attribute of processname.

Hence, here, I am assuming that you need the all the data under one column.

In the code below, I have basically just added two more rows using `UNION` keyword, and hence the underhanded coding of renaming it as the other column.

```
select 
    pro.processname
from 
    TBWORKFLOWPROCESS pro
    LEFT JOIN TBLSTAPP app on app.applicationtype = pro.workflowid
where
    pro.sequenceno >=10 
    and pro.workflowid = 1 

union

select
    app.isforreconsideration as 'processname'
from
    TBWORKFLOWPROCESS pro
    LEFT JOIN TBLSTAPP app on app.applicationtype = pro.workflowid
where
    sequenceno >=10 
    and pro.workflowid = 1

union

select app.isforamendment as 'processname'
from
    TBWORKFLOWPROCESS pro
    LEFT JOIN TBLSTAPP app on app.applicationtype = pro.workflowid
where
    sequenceno >=10 
    and pro.workflowid = 1
```

P.S. : I am very much sure that this code is not very correct and I may have touched the nerve of one too many, but if you could give the type of data, each column holds and the examples of which kind of data, you want as output, many others would be able to help.